# EF Code First Get FK related Values without Entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity

I have following Vehicle entity

```
class Vehicle 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string PlatNo {get; set;}
    public int VehicleTypeId {get; set;}
}
```

VehicleTypeId property is a FK of another database table that store all VehicleTypes. This is a lookup table with some basic Vehicle types generated through db script and there is no EF entity for VehicleType. the structure of the table is as follows:

```
VehicleTypeId    VehicleType 
-----------------------------
1                BMW
2                Honda
...
```

Now I want to display list of Vehicles with their Id, PlatNo, VehicleTypeId and VehicleType. How can I join Vehicle with VehicleTypes table and what should be the query to display vehicles list in following format.

```
Id    PlatNo    VehicleTypeId    VehicleType
---------------------------------------------
440   ABC-4848  1                BMW
441   ABC-4849  2                Honda
```

Comment: Your VehicleType is in your db, but not as an entity ? So write Raw SQL : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx But your scenario looks quite weird...

Comment: yes, it seems weird but I used VehicleTypeId and VehicleType just for clarity otherwise they are actualy Id and Description and they are available in a lookup table in database which is just used to fill dropdowns thats why I didnt created entity for lookup table.

Comment: Well, even for dropdown, I use entities... I don't see the point there. What would be the problem to put it as an entity ?

Comment: ok i am creating entity for lookup table too. Thanks alot for your replies.